# Performance of CGAL 3d line and triangle intersection

Tags: 3d, geometry, intersection, cgal

Has anyone used CGAL 3d line and triangle intersection? How is its performance compared to the **fast minimum storage ray triangle intersection** [algorithm](http://www.cs.virginia.edu/~gfx/Courses/2003/ImageSynthesis/papers/Acceleration/Fast%20MinimumStorage%20RayTriangle%20Intersection.pdf)? Thanks.

Comment: Going on other intersection tests, CGAL is generally quite a lot slower than hand rolled tests. The big benefit is they are guaranteed to be robust, and to "just work"